# SQL WHERE In a many-to-many or many-to-many empty

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know a way to simplify this WHERE expression?

```
WHERE        (
                    (@UserSpecialtyID in
                        (
                            SELECT      CharacteristicSpecialties_Id
                            FROM        ModalityVariantSpecialty
                            WHERE       ModalityVariants_Id = ModalityVariants.Id
                        )
                    ) 
                    OR 
                    NOT EXISTS
                        (
                            SELECT      CharacteristicSpecialties_Id
                            FROM        ModalityVariantSpecialty
                            WHERE       ModalityVariants_Id = ModalityVariants.Id
                        )
                )
```

Comment: Could you post the whole statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE (
        @UserSpecialtyID in
        (
           SELECT      COALESCE(CharacteristicSpecialties_Id, A.A)
           FROM        (SELECT @UserSpecialtyID A) A LEFT JOIN ModalityVariantSpecialty
           ON          ModalityVariants_Id = ModalityVariants.Id
        )
      )
```

this works well if `CharacteristicSpecialties_Id` is a NON NULLABLE field.

Comment: What is the overhead of COALESCE?

Comment: @CodeGrue almost negligible in this case

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should probably work but Im not exactly clear on the relationships for your tables.  I could probably give a better example if you could explain the relationships.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM MadalityVariants mv
LEFT JOIN ModalityVariantSpecialty mvs on mvs.ModalityVariants_ID = mv.ID 
WHERE
  @UserSpecialtyID  = mvs.CharacteristicSpecialties_ID
  OR 
  mvs.CharacteristicSpecialties_ID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt:

```
WHERE   @UserSpecialtyID = COALESCE
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 CharacteristicSpecialties_Id
        FROM    ModalityVariantSpecialty
        WHERE   ModalityVariants_Id = ModalityVariants.Id
        ORDER BY
                CASE WHEN CharacteristicSpecialties_Id = UserSpecialtyID THEN 1 
                     ELSE 2 END ASC
        ), @UserSpecialtyID)
```

- If both ModalityVariants_Id and UserSpecialtyID match, the subquery returns CharacteristicSpecialties_Id, and the `where` succeeds
- If only ModalityVariants_Id matches, the subquery returns a different ID, and the `where` fails
- If neither matches, the subquery returns NULL, the COALESCE returns @UserSpecialtyID, and the `where` succeeds

Probably clearest is a variety of John Hartsock's answer, with a subquery to ensure the `left join` doesn't add any rows.

```
select  *
from    ModalityVariants mv
left join 
        (
        select  distinct ModalityVariants_ID
        ,       CharacteristicSpecialties_ID
        from    ModalityVariantSpecialty
        ) as mvs
on      mvs.ModalityVariants_ID = mv.ID 
where   @UserSpecialtyID  = mvs.CharacteristicSpecialties_ID
        OR 
        mvs.CharacteristicSpecialties_ID is null
```

I'll vote for John's answer :)

Comment: why the added complication? It seems to me that the Coalesce and SubQuery would actually make this run slower.  Wouldnt a left join be easier?

Comment: @John Hartsock: Well, a left join might add extra rows if more than one row contains a matching `CharacteristicSpecialties_ID`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this is a WHERE clause of a SELECT on the table ModalityVariants

Would this work (The SQL is not tested)?

```
SELECT *
FROM ModalityVariants
LEFT OUTER JOIN ModalityVariantSpeciality 
                ON ModalityVariants.Id = ModalityVariants_ID
WHERE CharacteristicSpecialities_Id = @UserSpecialityID or    
      CharacteristicSpecialities_Id is NULL
```